# how to install my Monodroid app to my HTC device?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'd like to install my Monodroid app on HTC Android as a testing. how to? Please share me any step by step link. Android set up is ok but i dont find any link monodroid setup to device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried following the ["Set up Device for Deployment"](http://mono-android.net/Documentation/Guides/Set_up_Device_for_Development) guide? It's specifically for a Nexus One, but I would at least try following that as far as you can.

Comment: @programmerist: Yes, which is why I said you should just try following it as far as you can. I'd expect *most* of it to be the same.

Comment: A Nexus One _is_ an HTC phone.

Comment: @jonp: That's what I thought too, but I wasn't quite sure enough of whether there might be *some* differences to speak too confidently :)